# Графический интерфейс python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Radiobutton  
import random
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox 

  
a = ['Выпей кофе','Поговорить с близкими!','Отдохни сегодня','Хорошо бы тебе прогуляться','Напиши друзьям','Покушай здоровой еды','Сделай разминку']
def clicked():
    lbl.configure(text=random.choice(a))
def angr():  
    res = "Привет {}, вот твое предсказание".format(txt.get())  
    lbl.configure(text=res)   

window = Tk()  
window.title('Добро пожаловать в приложение "ПеЧеНьКи"')  
window.geometry('1400x1250')  
selected = IntVar() 
txt = Entry(window,width=10)  
txt.grid(column=10, row=0)
lbl1 = Label(window, text="Введите свой возраст:")  
lbl1.grid(column=18, row=0)
lbl2.grid(column=20, row=0)   
rad1 = Radiobutton(window,text='Понедельник', value=1, variable=selected)  
rad2 = Radiobutton(window,text='Вторник', value=2, variable=selected)  
rad3 = Radiobutton(window,text='Среда', value=3, variable=selected)
rad4 = Radiobutton(window,text='Четверг', value=4, variable=selected)  
rad5 = Radiobutton(window,text='Пятница', value=5, variable=selected)  
rad6 = Radiobutton(window,text='Суббота', value=6, variable=selected)
rad7 = Radiobutton(window,text='Воскресенье', value=7, variable=selected)  
btn = Button(window, text="За печенькой!", command=clicked, bg="black", fg="yellow") 
angr1 = Button(window, text="Я ввёл имя!", command=angr ,bg="black", fg="yellow")  
lbl = Label(window)  
rad1.grid(column=0, row=0)  
rad2.grid(column=1, row=0)  
rad3.grid(column=2, row=0)
rad4.grid(column=3, row=0)  
rad5.grid(column=4, row=0)  
rad6.grid(column=5, row=0)
rad7.grid(column=6, row=0)  
btn.grid(column=3, row=3)  
lbl.grid(column=0, row=1)
angr1.grid(column=13, row=0)
combo = Combobox(window)  
combo['values'] = ('1-5','6-10','11-15','16-20','21-25','26-35','36-50','>50','конфиденциальная информация')  
combo.current('конфиденциальная информация')  
combo.grid(column=20, row=0)  
window.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В чём именно у вас проблема? Пожалуйста, опишите подробнее что именно у вас не работает, какую ошибку получаете или что работает не так

Comment: исправил посмотрите на ошибки на скрине

Comment: Вот, уже лучше) Ещё один вам совет: Ошибки вставляйте текстом, а не скрином ;)

Comment: Во-первых, вы где потеряли в своём коде объявление переменной `lbl2`. Выводит, что её просто нет -_-

Comment: то есть нужно так?def angr():  
    res = "Привет {}, вот твое предсказание".format(txt.get())  
    lbl2.configure(text=res) а что еще

Comment: Нет, вы не так поняли. У вас нету вообще объявления это переменной и на строке размещения `lbl2.grid(column=20, row=0)` уже ошибка. То есть, даже не создаётся этот елемент

Comment: Да не за что пока XD Кстати, в программировании по-другому никак ;) Рано или поздно тошнить начинает и ты либо преодоливаешь всё это и самосовершенствуешься, либо бросаешь и ищешь другие пути)

Comment: Писать код в интерактивном режиме - это конечно тот еще садомазохизм. Не пробовали записывать код в файл, потом запускать его целиком, вместо того чтобы вводить программу по одной строчке?

Answer (score 1):

**Ошибка в упаковке:**

Вы применили метод **.grid** к несуществующему лейблу **lbl2**

```
lbl2.grid(column=20, row=0)
```

Нужно его просто создать и привязать к окну или фрейму:

```
lbl2 = Label(window,text = 'Как то так')
```

**Далее**

Работа с combobox:

В `combo.current()`
в скобках задаётся индекс, а не строка

```
combo.current(8)
```

Отрицательный индекс `(-1)` , насколько я понял, не поддерживается

Теперь всё запускается и работает

[image: 1]
[image: 2]